# Weird bug with phonegap ios

Tags: ios, cordova

I am writing a iphone application using phonegap and ios. I have a weird problem. I have a `NSString` which holds a json string in my objective c plugin class. And then I call the callback function provided by running `Phonegap.exec`, however the callback neither the success or failure gets called. Here is some code:

```
PluginResult* pluginResult = [PluginResult resultWithStatus: PGCommandStatus_OK messageAsString: jsonString ];
        [self writeJavascript:[pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:self.callbackID]];
```

my success callback simply alerts the argument passed. The weird thing is that, if I pass in a non jsonString for example replacing `jsonString` with just some regular message, say `@"Hello-word"` then it works, and the success callback gets called and the argument gets alerted. Anyone have any idea what going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a literal quote in my jsonString, but my jsonString was hardcoded. Instead of doing this, I just used a messageAsDictionary with the appropriate mapped values, and I could still interpret the data recieved my javascript as json object.